# How to stop Azure Event Hubs service?

Tags: azure-eventhub

Is there an ability to stop/start Azure Event Hubs service manually? The primary goal is to stress test our services under the condition of Event Hubs service being down, but one can obviously think of other use cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of options for testing error cases.

1. Block network connection by firewall rules. This is a good way to simulate a service-down incident case.
2. You can disable eventhub and re-enable it back.
   [image]

Comment: Hi Serkant. Thanks for the options. These work well for the stress testing case :+1:
But for some other cases, one may want to restart (or stop/start) the entire EventHubs namespace, just like it is possible to do with Azure App Services. Can you think of a way doing that?

Comment: Unfortunately, Event Hubs doesn't provide a similar stop/start capability.  You can also try deprovisioning namespace which should generate EndpointNotFound or HostNameNotFound errors.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably a useful option in some scenarios. We can also delete individual event hubs/consumer groups to simulate different error conditions.